# Batch- Hiding Text/Disabling or Enabling Values?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I'm making an RPG game in Batch and I need to make it so that if the player hasn't bought a certain weapon it doesn't show up as an option to use. Currently, I have a battle system in which you press a key to use a weapon you have. However, I don't know how to make it so that if you don't own a certain weapon, you can't use it.

I also want it so that even if the text doesn't show, the user still can't use it if they don't have it. For example, if you don't have a sword but you know that to use it you press s, I don't want it to work unless you have it. That way people can't just cheat.

Please help!

Here is the code:

```
if %sword1% equ true echo 2-Tachi

set /p e="Weapon to equip:"
pause
```

I don't want the user to just type 2 and have the Tachi. I want it so that they have to 
have the weapon to use it.

Comment: sounds like a job for `if`. Can you show us your (relevant) code you already have, or do we have to invent the game ourselves?

Comment: Ok, the code is added (albeit its basic). please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set w1=sword
set w2=bow
set w3=axe
set w4=machinegun
set w5=warbow

set w1?=true
set w2?=false
set w3?=true
set w4?=false
set w5?=false

:loop
echo ----------
for /L %%i in (1,1,9) do (
  if !w%%i?!==true echo %%i - !w%%i!
)
set /p e="Weapon to equip: "
if !w%e%?!==true ( 
 echo you have choosed: !W%e%!
) else (
 echo you don't have one.
 goto :loop
)
echo now, that you have a !W%e%!, go and fight!
echo Bamm - Wush - Ouch
if %random% lss 10000 ( 
  echo Congratulations, you have found a %w4%.
  set "w4?=true"
)
pause
goto :loop
```

**EDIT** (explanations to the code)

the first block of `set` just sets the names of the weapons.

The second block of `set` sets it they are available to the player. (in gameplay, usually there is only one available in the beginning, others can be found or bought during the game).
The `?` in the variable names is nothing special, only a char like any letter. If it confuses you, you can also use something like `B` (like `b`oolean): `set w5B=false`

The `for`-loop is the heart of this code. It displays all available weapons (it tries `w1` to `w9`. You can adapt it to process hundreds or even thousands of items (it starts from `1`, increments by `1` until `9`))

If it is available (`true`), it echoes the number (`%%i`) and the weapon-name.

`!w%%i?!` is a bit tricky. %%i is the "loop-counter" (1,2,3,...,9), so `w%%i?` will translate to (for example) `w4?` (and `w%%i` to `w4`.

Because you need the variable with that name, you'll have to put it between `%`, but as `%%i` is already part of the variable, the interpreter would get confused. For that, we use `delayed expansion` (search for it in stackoverflow, there are more findings than you can read) and therefore can use `!` instead of `%`, so the complete variable is named `!w%%i?!` (remember: the `?` is just a letter). (don't be depressed, if you don't get it the first time, just play around with it and it will make sense to you some day).

The `if` after the `set /p e="Weapon to equip: "` checks, if the weapon is available (`true`) if yes, fine, if no then error/try again.

The `if %random%`... part shows you how to make an item available (`true`). You can also make one unavailable by setting the flag to `false`.) Wheather you do that like me as a finding in a fight, or in a shop (buy/sell), the doing is the same.

I'm sure, you already guessed, that you'll have to replace `echo Bamm - Wush - Ouch` with some code for a fight.

Comment: @alex: it's there to show, how you can add (or remove) items. A little voice in my head told me, that this would have been the next question.

Comment: @Stephan I'm a little confused as to what the loop does (especially the top part). It works, but I would like to know what all the code means so I could use it in the future. I'm new at Batch and I want to learn all I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to come up to a solution since the user will be able to edit the .bat file anyway? Wouldn't it be better to write it in C++ or C#?

Comment: Yes, but I'm making this for my friends and don't plan to release it to all. Since they have little programming experience, they wouldn't know where to look. If you have a solution, please tell me. :)

Comment: It's really hard to figure out a solution until we see some "relevant" code to work with.